# Function which asks for age

Tags: python, function, loops, logic

I need this to ask for an age, but if the age is under 11 or over 100 to reject it and to also reject anything but integers. If a number put in is out of the given range or isn't an integer I need it to loop back and ask again

```
def PlayerAgeFunction():
   VALID = True
   while VALID == True:
      PlayerAge = int(raw_input('ENTER YOUR AGE: '))
      if PlayerAge == type(int):
          VALID = False
     elif PlayerAge != type(int):
         print 'THAT IS NOT A NUMBER.'
   return PlayerAge
```

I looked on here for an answer before but what I found didn't help.
please can someone help, thank you.

Comment: @Lattyware: not entering an integer, for one..

Comment: You should really read http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/ about how your python code should look like.

Comment: Also, `if PlayerAge == type(int):` is not doing what you think it does.

Comment: @ThiefMaster: But this isn't Python, it's Fortran... oh wait... it __IS__ Python?!!

Comment: Most of this isn't doing what he thinks it does.

Comment: No need to test `== True` in an `if` statement either. That's what `if` *means*..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def prompt_age(min=11, max=100):
    while True:
        try:
            age = int(raw_input('ENTER YOUR AGE: '))
        except ValueError:
            print 'Please enter a valid number'
            continue
        if not min <= age <= max:
            print 'You are too young/old'
            continue
        return age
```

Comment: The OP asks for it to loop until the age is in range, so you really want `while not (min <= age <= max):`.

Comment: True, just forgot the `continue`. I think that's cleaner. No need to use the variable outside the loop.

Comment: You're welcome. But please try to actually understand the code and read the PEP8 document I linked in the question's comments. Otherwise you'll end up writing horrible python code nobody will want to read or fix in the future.